# Отправка формы Яндекс Деньги с файла контролера

Tags: codeigniter

Вечер в радость!

Моя задача: пользователь переходит на страницу с которой происходит оплата от Яндекс денег. Сайт должен записать данные в БД, которые вводит клиент в форму и перенаправить его на сайте Яндекс Деньги с параметрами, которые он ввел.
Если первую задачу я выполнил, то не знаю как отправить пользователя дальше.
Он должен перейти по форме:

```
<form method="POST" action="https://money.yandex.ru/quickpay/confirm.xml"> 
    <input type="hidden" name="receiver" value="410013229143888"> 
    <input type="hidden" name="formcomment" value="Оплата через AIVA">
    <input type="hidden" name="quickpay-form" value="shop"> 
    <input type="hidden" name="targets" value="Оплата по счету"> 
    <input type="hidden" name="need-fio" value="false"> 
    <input type="hidden" name="need-email" value="false"> 
    <input type="hidden" name="need-phone" value="false"> 
    <input type="hidden" name="need-address" value="false"> 
    <input type="hidden" name="paymentType" value="PC">

    <input type="email" name="short-dest" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" placeholder="mail@mail.ru">
    <input type="text" id="comment" name="comment" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" placeholder="Необязательное поле">
    <input type="text" name="sum" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" value="200">

    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">ок</button>
</form>
```

Файл **view**

```
<?php echo form_open(site_url("payment/add_card_yandex_pro/"), array("" => "")) ?>


          <input type="email" name="short-dest" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" placeholder="mail@mail.ru">
          <input type="text" id="comment" name="comment" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" placeholder="Необязательное поле">
          <input type="text" name="sum" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" value="200">

          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">ок</button>
      <?php echo form_close() ?>
```

файл controler

```
public function add_card_yandex_pro()
{
    // Сохранение действия в истории операций
    $pay_method  = "Банковские карты Яндекс";
    $transaction = $this->common->nohtml($this->input->post("targets"));
    $name = $this->common->nohtml($this->input->post("formcomment"));
    $amount = $this->common->nohtml($this->input->post("sum"));
    $email = $this->common->nohtml($this->input->post("short-dest"));
    $comment = $this->common->nohtml($this->input->post("comment"));

    if(empty($name)) {
        $this->template->error(lang("error_79"));
    }


        $historyid = $this->payment_model->add_card_yandex(array(
        "pay_method" => $pay_method,
        "transaction" => $transaction,
        "name" => $name,
        "amount" => $amount,
        "email" => $email,
        "comment" => $comment,
        "timestamp" => time()
        )
    );

    $this->session->set_flashdata("globalmsg", lang("success_40"));
    redirect(site_url("pay_link"));

}
```

Как правильно прописать форму в контролере?
Рад и благодарен любой помощи или направлению.

Comment: т.е у вас пока конечная точка в контроллере? после записи в DB что вы делаете redirect(site_url("pay_link")); ??

Comment: Спасибо за внимание к моему вопросу! Я не знаю что делать после записи данных в БД. Я хочу отправить форму на яндекс, чтобы она открылась у пользователя.

Comment: В ответе напишу приблизительный пример что надо сделать

Comment: Арсен, это будет здорово!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

После того как вы записали информацию в базе, вам необходимо собрать информацию для отправки на Яндекс

```
$GET_params = 'receiver={номер кошелька}&';
$GET_params .= 'formcomment='Описание платежа'&';
$GET_params .= 'label={ваши любые данные которые Яндекс возвратит вам обратно}&';
$GET_params .= 'quickpay-form=shop&';
$GET_params .= 'targets=Описание платежа №2&';
$GET_params .= 'sum={сумма платежа}'&';
$GET_params .= 'paymentType={метод оплаты для покупателя: AC-кошелёк,PC-кредитка}&';
$GET_params .= 'successURL=Путь редиректа от яндекс';
$url = "https://money.yandex.ru/quickpay/confirm.xml?".$GET_params ." ";
```

и тут вы просто делаете редирект на ссылку 
`redirect($url)`